# Xcode Exception while running ibtool

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, macos

I recently updated to OS X El Capitan, and along with that Xcode 7.1.1. Now whenever I try to run a project in Xcode, I get an issue in the Main.storyboard saying: [IBUIViewControllerAutolayoutGuide shouldBeArchived]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fee7a5f8390.

As a result, it's impossible for me to run anything :-(. Does anyone have an idea as to what to do about this?

Thanks

Harry

Comment: add a breakpoint for exceptions and examine the backtrace